# freeze columns and rows

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing one application in asp.net 2010.

I want freezing functionality like in http://datatables.net/extras/fixedcolumns/ link.
I don't want to use any plug in. And also there is a functionality to show or hide specific columns. So in this situation freezing should work properly.

Any solution please?

I have found one solution from here:
http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/how-to-create-an-html-table-with-frozen-headers-and-columns/

It is working fine if don't show/hide any columns at client side.
But when i show/hide columns in freeze-section then width of freeze-section remain as it is hence create blank space at end. Actually width of table should be adjust automatically so that combination of both freeze and non-freeze section will create illusion of one table only.  Any Solution?

Comment: with out plug in ?? you want javascript ?? if no than forget you cannot do that

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to achieve this using the standard GridView.  I would suggest that you take a look at some third party tools where this option is available.  For example, to the [ASPxGridView](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/) control from DevExpress.  Here are links to a couple of demos:

[Customization Window](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Columns/CustomizationWindow.aspx)

[Fixed Columns](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/FixedColumns.aspx)